# RMI compatibility between JVM implementations

Tags: java, rmi

Are there any problems when calling methods over RMI when the server is running on an IBM JVM and the client on a Sun/Oracle JVM or vice versa.

In other words: Is the RMI protocol (not RMI-IIOP) in the Java specification and is it tested by the JCK?

I have found the documentation about the RMI protocol from Oracle but have not found a hint if the documentation is also valid for other JVM implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The RMI JRMP protocol is defined in the Java RMI Specification. That means it must be the same across all Java implementations, barring bugs, and barring non-Java implementations such as GNU CLASSPATH. The biggest problem you will encounter is mismatching serialVersionUIDs: you need to be careful to define them for all your own classes, and you need to avoid serializing JDK classes that aren't guaranteed to have stable serialized formats, e.g. Swing classes, as the Javadoc for every one of them tells you.